# How to capture the specific browser contents in Java?

Tags: java, web-scraping

I am accessing the website (**http://www.bacnet.org/Addenda/**) using **htmlunit** api library in Java.

I am able to get the contents of entire page but I would like to capture only specific area.

This is how I am fetching the page:

```
public static void getBACnetStandard() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, 
                                              MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.bacnet.org/Addenda/");
    String pageContent = page.asText();
    System.out.println(pageContent);
}
```

**I would like to capture the highlighted area (in RED box) from the entire page.**

[image]

Comment: If you have the raw source HTML for each page, then what is stopping use from using an xpath parser to find the content you want?

Comment: may be you can do it by "Web Scraping" technology.....

Answer (score 0):

First get the Id of Element on HtmlPage

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.bacnet.org/Addenda/");
// inspect target_div_id and get that Element here
HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("target_div_id");
```

or you want to use other custom attribute to fetch that DOM Element, like I'm giving example using target_class_value

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.bacnet.org/Addenda/");
// inspect target_class_value and get that Element here
HtmlDivision div = page.getByXPath("//div[@class='target_class_value']");
```